# Finding complex eigenvalues

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, determinant

For the matrix \begin{pmatrix}1/2 & 1 & 3/4\\2/3 & 0 & 0\\0 & 1/3 & 0\end{pmatrix}
Find the eigenvalues and corresponding eigenvectors. I did this with an online calculator and got that there were $2$ complex eigenvalues, but I am struggling to do the work by hand. I know that I have to get it to the characteristic polynomial with the determinant of $A -\lambda \cdot I$ but after that I am lost.

Comment: As long as you do the algebra correctly, there is no particular difference between finding real and complex eigenvalues.  If you post your working, someone will probably be able to find any errors or help you where you are stuck.

Comment: Well, what did you come up with for the characteristic polynomial?

Comment: What appears to be at issue here is that the _real_ eigenvalue is irrational (WA goes "full Cardano" on this), so it's a bit challenging to get the two complex eigenvalues by hand.  Are you quite sure the matrix is correct?  As it stands, this seems a strange problem to give a student to do as an exercise.

Comment: why don't you multiply your matrix by $12$ and find the eigenvalues. then you can divide the eigenvalues by $12$ to get back.

Answer (score 0):

If $A=\begin{pmatrix}1/2 & 1 & 3/4\\2/3 & 0 & 0\\0 & 1/3 & 0\end{pmatrix}$, $|A-\lambda I|=det \begin {pmatrix}1/2-\lambda & 1 & 3/4\\2/3 & -\lambda & 0\\0 & 1/3 & -\lambda\end{pmatrix}=\frac{3}{4}\times\frac{2}{9}-0-\lambda((\frac{1}{2}-\lambda)(-\lambda)-\frac{2}{3})$.

Hence we have to solve, $-\lambda^3+\frac{1}{2}\lambda^2+\frac{2}{3}\lambda+\frac{1}{6}=0$.

Comment: This is the exact polynomial that I have, I get three roots. one at about $1.183$ and then $-.341$ (plus or minus) $.15609$

Comment: your first root is correct. But other 2 are not. See here http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=-x%5E3%2B%281%2F2%29+x%5E2%2B%282%2F3%29+x%2B%281%2F6%29%3D0  You have $-0.341$ plus or minus $ 0.15609 i$

Comment: I just forgot to put the i in for imaginary, so my roots are correct.

Answer (score 0):

let me consider the matrix $$A=\pmatrix{6&12&9\\8&0&0\\0&4&0}.$$ the eigenvalues are given by $$0=det\pmatrix{6-x&12&9\\8&-x&0\\0&4&-x}=-x\left(-x(6-x)-96)\right)-4(-72)=-x^3+6x^2+96x+288$$ has a real root at $x = 14.193354$ so the original matrix has an eigevvalue $1.18277$; not a nice number.